# Query SELECT * FROM multiple tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables that looks like this:

Post table:

```
ID     |     photo      |   ident
-------------------------------------
80     |    img/photo1  |   ACH3882
81     |    img/photo2  |   SHD8837
82     |    img/photo3  |   SFF4837
83     |    img/photo4  |   DLL3266
```

Kudos table:

```
ID     |     photo_id   |   ident_id
-------------------------------------
1      |       80       |   SHD8837
2      |       83       |   ACH3882
3      |       82       |   SHD8837
```

How it works: I am trying to add kudos system to my website. I have already set up the tables like shows above. Each user has its own `ident`. When a user press the kudos button, the `ident` of the user and the id for the `photo` is stored in the kudos table, like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id']; // get id through query string
$ident = $_SESSION["ident"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO kudos (photo_id, ident_id) VALUES ('$id', '$ident')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    mysqli_close($link); // Close connection
    header("location:index.php"); // redirects to all records page
    exit;
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Now I want to display the number of kudos given for each photo. Currently I only query one table, but I need to query the second one also to get the value from that table also. This is how I query the first table:

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT * FROM post;
       if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
              $num_rows = 0;
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $num_rows++;
                  
                  
                  /* <!-- Feed start --> */
                  echo "{$row['photo']}.";
                  echo '<a class="btn" href="kudos.php?id=';
                  echo "{$row['id']}";
                  echo '">';
                  echo '★ Give kudos</a>';
                  echo ' 0';  <- This is where I want the number count of kudos gives to show up.
                  ... and so on
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: `$id = $_GET['id'];` this is open to SQL injection, please sanitize that GET variable before passing to the query.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM post;` < you didn't close that off. Bad paste?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I just added `... and so on` insted of posting the whole code. The rest is just some text and `$result->free();
          }
      ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Select p.id,p.photo,p.indent from post p
Left join kudos k on
p.id = k.photo_id

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to join tables?

```
SELECT  Post.id as post, count(Kudos.ident_id) as kudos
FROM Post
LEFT JOIN Kudos ON Post.id=Kudos.photo_id  
GROUP BY Post.id;
```

This should return you smth like:

```
post_id ... kudosCount
```

Read more about joins here:
[SQL joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Sorry, but should I use that code instead of `INSERT INTO kudos ...`?

Comment: @AmenCarb INSERT is one thig. Its how you store it. You question was how to get data from DB, so my answer explained that